# Text is unreadable at fov's edges with HTC Vive

Tags: unity, text, virtual-reality, htc-vive

Not sure if this is the good place to ask or if should asked it in photography, sorry if it's not.

I was trying stuff in Unity for a vr game based on text but as I tested it I saw that the center of the field of vision is pretty sharp but the edges are blurry/"spread toward the center".
Tests were made with the first HTC Vive and it was the first time I used it (https://www.vive.com/eu/product/)

The problem is, high text quality is really important, it has to be the cleanest it can be in the entire fov.

Does Unity can be tweaked to solve this problem ?
Is this a problem with the physical headset's lenses ?
Can it be fixed by changing headset configuration or something ?

Also, as this is linked to the subject, is there some way to get a wider fov without increasing the "blurry edges" effect ?

Comment: Nothing about this seems particularly off-topic. Generally you should avoid asking multiple questions in a single post, but in this case, they all come back to the same question of "how can I make text readable at the FOV edge on the Vive".